# Docker doesn't expose port

Tags: docker

I create a docker container for a flask app but it does not export the port, and the app runs normal on port 5000.

```
docker run -P <image_name >
```

`INFO - 2021-04-13 16:50:50,638 - _internal -  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

I run `docker ps` and see that the app is exposed on port

`docker ps CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                     NAMES 2abf050cfc0d   condatest   "conda run --no-capt…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:49153->5000/tcp   wonderful_wozniak`

But I try to acces using the browser `localhost:49153` and can not see anything.

Comment: Your flask app needs to listen on `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: How can I change the 0.0.0.0, to 127.0.0.1?